# Cannot read property ____ of null

Tags: javascript, object, methods, null, es6-class

As an exercise, I went through [this tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-game-loop-in-javascript/), then attempted to create a version that puts everything into its own class to clean it up so I can add some of my own additions. The issue is that I am running into an error that doesn't seem to make any sense. (all the commented stuff is filled in on my end, but it didn't seem relevant to the question) `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lastRender' of null at loop (game-loop.js:13)`

```
class GameLoop {
  constructor(player, canvas) {
    // Set other variables
    this.lastRender = 0;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.loop);
  }

  loop(timestamp) {
    let progress = timestamp - this.lastRender; // This is ln. 13 in the actual program

    this.update(progress);
    this.draw();

    this.lastRender = timestamp;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.loop);
  }

  update(progress) {
    // Update function
  }

  draw() {
    // Draw function
  }

}
```

Additionally when I remove the lastRender variable from the class, it stops giving me that error, but instead says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of null at loop (game-loop.js:15)`

Comment: `lastRender` is not defined for your class `GameLoop`. Just make sure it is defined.

Comment: @Abdullah Khan I don't know what you mean

Comment: What is `lastRender` in your class `GameLoop`? When you say `this.lastRender` it referes to the objects property `lastRender`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use `.bind()` to make `this` have the right value. Change this:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(this.loop);
```

to this:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this));
```

When you pass a method as a callback as you are doing with `this.loop`, the value of `this` is not passed, only the reference to the method.  So, when `window.requestAnimationFrame()` calls `loop()` it isn't calling it in a way that will make `this` have the right value inside the method and thus you get the error you see when you try to use `this.anything`.

Comment: I tried this already but it didn't seem to change anything so I took it out.

Comment: Also what is the difference between using bind and not?

Comment: @ZacharyElkins - You need to use it all places you pass a method as a callback (at least the two places you show `window.requestAnimationFrame()`.  There's more explanation in my answer now.

Comment: Weirdly enough, It works now. I might have forgotten something maybe? Odd.

Comment: Continuing the same logic,  `this.loop=this.loop.bind(this)` in the constructor allows `loop` to be passed to the animation requests without binding it on every iteration.

Comment: @traktor53 - Yes, that would work too.